# norm of the derivative for multivariable mapping

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, hilbert-spaces

Let $m,n,d\in \mathbb{N}^*$. We define the following $C^1$ mapping: $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n \times\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$. Do we have the following :

$$ \|Df(\cdot,\cdot)\|_{\mathbb{R}^{(n+m)\times d}} = \|D_xf(\cdot,\cdot) \|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}} + \|D_y f(\cdot,\cdot)\|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}},$$
or we only have the inequality
$$\|Df(\cdot,\cdot)\|_{\mathbb{R}^{(n+m)\times d}} \leq\|D_xf(\cdot,\cdot) \|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}} + \|D_y f(\cdot,\cdot) \|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}},$$

Answer (score 0):

Equality holds for the $\ell^1$ norm on matrix entries, but is not generally true with other norms.

Comment: What about $L^{\infty}$ norm do we have $\sup_{B(0_{\mathbb{R}^{n+m}},1)}\|Df(\cdot,\cdot)\|_{\mathbb{R}^{(n+m)\times d}} \leq \sup_{B(0_{\mathbb{R}^n},1)}\|D_xf(\cdot,\cdot) \|_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}} +\sup_{B(0_{\mathbb{R}^m},1)} \|D_y f(\cdot,\cdot) \|_{\mathbb{R}^{m\times d}},$